# How can I avoid Makefile failure if file doesn't exist?

Tags: makefile

I've got a dependency between a few files, where one is generated from the other. For example `bar.txt` is needed to generate `foo-temp.xml` is needed to generate the final `foo.xml` file. In my Makefile this is expressed as follows:

```
foo-temp.xml: bar.txt
    do-magic -o foo-temp.xml bar.txt

foo.xml: foo-temp.xml
    do-more-magic -o foo.xml foo-temp.xml
```

As long as all files exist, everything works smoothly. But there are instances where I provide `foo-temp.xml` manually instead of generating it from `bar.txt`; in fact, `bar.txt` doesn't even exist in that case.

How can I express this "non-existence" in my Makefile without having it fail because `bar.txt` does not exist?

Comment: Is `do-more-magic -o foo-temp.xml foo.xml` a typo here or in your original? Shouldn't that be `do-more-magic -o foo.xml foo-temp.xml`? Not that it affects this issue.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Oops, you're right, fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best way but it should work (assuming bar.txt itself never needs to be created via another target).

```
foo-temp.xml: $(wildcard bar.txt)
```

The [`wildcard`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) function returns the list of files that match the patterns and removes those that don't. This also happens to work for filenames with no wildcard/globbing characters in them.

Alternatively (and a bit more verbosely)

```
foo-temp.xml: $(and $(realpath bar.txt),bar.txt)
```

Same basic idea but [`realpath`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) returns a "canonical absolute name" so you can't use its result directly (unless you want an absolute path there) so instead we use the fact that the [`and`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html) function short-circuits to only generate output when `realpath` returns a non-empty value.

If `bar.txt` needs to be generated itself than neither of those solutions will work however as it will prevent `bar.txt` from being a prerequisite unless it already exists (though once it does the normal make process will work).

If this is the case then you could try using `make -o foo-temp.xml foo.xml` to tell make that `foo-temp.xml` is infinitely old which should short-circuit make attempting to remake it (and process its prerequisites) and should let the `foo.xml: foo-temp.xml` rule work (assuming `foo.xml` doesn't exist or is older than the `foo-temp.xml` you created manually).

Comment: A combination of both worked. I used the `$(and ..)` function, actually, because it allows me to add dependencies on global variables too: `$(and $(ROOTFILE), bla.txt)` which generates a dependency iff the main `$ROOTFILE` and `bla.txt` exist.

Comment: @Jens Yup, `and` for conditional things like that is useful. A word of advice though. Avoid extraneous spaces in make contexts. They aren't always stripped/ignored where you expect they might be. So I suggest `$(and $(ROOTFILE),bla.txt)` instead of `$(and $(ROOTFILE), bla.txt)` even though I don't think it matters in this case.

Comment: Ugh, I didn't know! Thanks :)